# Dropdown on click of Image in React

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to have a dropdown of options like Sign out and Update Account on the click of a profile image.

I'm using Select from react-select

```
<Select
            options={dropdownOptions}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
```

Is there a way to make the select be an image that when you click drops down options?

Comment: As a tip, it IS possible but this select is supposed for form inputs' selects. You may have a hard time using this component for that objective. I suggest you to look for some other components (like [material dropdowns](https://mui.com/components/menus/)), it may make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className="dropdown show">
    <button className="btn dropdown-toggle" style={{border: "transparent"}}
            id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <img className='profileImage' src={profileIcon} alt='Profile'/>
    </button>
    
    <div className="dropdown-menu">                
        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="/myProfile">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="/myDashboard">My Dashboard </a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"/></li>
        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="/signOut">Signout</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```